# Prana Side Car Service to Service Call

Tags: node.js, netflix-eureka

I am running into a strange problem.  I have implemented a Prana Sidecar with a nodejs based service.  The Node service uses prana host uri to locate and call another service. All of the services are in docker containers.  It looks like I have to directly call the node service first in order to get prana to work.  Otherwise I am getting the following error:

```
21:00:46.080 [http-nio-9003-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping - Mapping [/sqlprana] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController@44cddafb] and 1 interceptor
21:00:46.106 [http-nio-9003-exec-1] INFO  o.s.c.n.z.filters.ProxyRouteLocator - Finding route for path: /sqlprana
21:00:46.106 [http-nio-9003-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.c.n.z.filters.ProxyRouteLocator - servletPath=/zuul
21:00:46.107 [http-nio-9003-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.c.n.z.filters.ProxyRouteLocator - path=/sqlprana
21:00:46.107 [http-nio-9003-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.c.n.z.filters.ProxyRouteLocator - Matching pattern:/sqlparser/**
21:00:46.108 [http-nio-9003-exec-1] WARN  o.s.c.n.z.f.pre.PreDecorationFilter - No route found for uri: /sqlprana
```

The problem does not happen if I directly hit the node service.

Comment: It looks like there is a latency issue between prana sidecar and the node service.  Not sure which configuration setting needs to be set.  My config is as follows      registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 15,     lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds:  30

Comment: Can you please drop the git url of your project ?